# Heroku Application crashing on startup discordjs

Tags: heroku, discord.js

```
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072745+00:00 app[worker.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072757+00:00 app[worker.1]:   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072757+00:00 app[worker.1]:                  ^
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072758+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072758+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: invalid ELF header
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072758+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072759+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072759+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072759+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072760+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072760+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072760+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072761+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072761+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072761+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072762+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072762+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072766+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-03-13T12:28:53.072766+00:00 app[worker.1]: Node.js v17.7.1
2022-03-13T12:28:53.205192+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Whenever I start my heroku application it crashes with the error above
I cant figure out why its doing this, the bot works completely fine running it off vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this question => [Simple REST app working in local but not in heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65871698/simple-rest-app-working-in-local-but-not-in-heroku), the error happens because you have committed the `node_modules` folder to your repository. The `node_modules` folder contains all the modules you install, and some of them are incompatible with Heroku. So all you have to do is remove it from your repository and untrack the `node_modules` folder by doing:

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -m "Remove node_modules from repository"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: this did resolve the issue but now im getting this error saying i dont have module 'colors' https://pastebin.com/Vyy9yvCx

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you earn enough reputation. If it's not a duplicate, tailor the answer to this specific question.

Comment: That happens because there is no module called `colors` in your `package.json` file. So all you have to do is `npm install colors --save`